# C# passing a compare class as a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new in C#. I tried to create a heap structure and I came up with this question: How do I pass a "compare-class" to my heap structure? I mean, I want to create a heap like: `Heap<int, cmp<int>> heap = new Heap<int, cmp<int>>();` where "cmp" is a compare-class which makes the heap in a priority order (I took the idea of priority_queue in C++). I have succeed (I think) in making a Heap that takes a max-min comparer:

```
public class Heap<T, Priority>
    where Priority : IPriority<T>, new()
    where T : IComparable
{
    private List<T> storage = new List<T>();        
    private Priority HeapPriority = new Priority();
    private void UpHeap(int position)
    {            
        for(var i = position; i > 0; i = (i - 1) >> 1)
        {
            // Check whether storage[i] is more Priority than storage[(i - 1) >> 1]
            if (HeapPriority.MorePriority(storage[i], storage[(i - 1) >> 1])
                .CompareTo(storage[i]) == 0)
            {
                storage.Swap(i, (i - 1) >> 1);
            }
            else break;
        }
    }   
}
```

and here is the IPriority interface:

```
public interface IPriority<T>
    where T : IComparable
{
    T MorePriority(T a, T b);
}
```

and I used the Heap like this:

```
public class Min<T> : IPriority<T>
        where T : IComparable
    {
        public Min() { }
        public T MorePriority(T a, T b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) <= 0 ? a : b;
        }
    }
static public void TestHeap()
    {
        var heap = new Heap<Pair<long, int>, Min<Pair<long, int>>>();            
        heap.Add(Pair<long, int>(10, 20));
        heap.Add(Pair<long, int>(21, 100));
        // ...
    }
```

but I want a heap that sorts the items by any way that I want, not only max-min order. Moreover, is there a way to use "Ipriority.MorePriority" as a static method?, because it's working just like a static method. Can anyone give me some advices?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The obvious answer is to use `IComparer<T>`. Why aren't you? There many possible ways to approach the problem. Please try _something_. If you have a _specific_ question after that, post a new question with a good [mcve] that shows clearly the specific issue you are having.

Comment: thank you. I'll keep that in mind. This is my first question so I'm sorry for asking something stupid

Comment: No question is stupid. The problem here is that there's not any indication that you spent any time researching possible answers, never mind what specific problem you ran into in trying to implement any solution. It's fine if you missed the obvious and that's in fact the answer, but even someone who misses the obvious answer would presumably try _something_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest treating `IComparer<T>` as a *dependence* and pass it to constructor; something like this:

```
  // You can create a heap of any type, right? 
  // But in some cases (e.g. Heap<Button>) you should provide a comparer:
  // how to compare Button instances   
  public class Heap<T> {
    //TODO: implement here Heap as well as Unheap method having IComparer<T> m_Comparer
    ...
    private IComparer<T> m_Comparer;

    // comparer = null - if comparer is not provided, try to use default one
    // if it's possible (e.g. in case of Heap<double>)
    public Heap(IComparer<T> comparer = null): base() {
      // Do we have a default comparer (e.g. for int, double, string)?
      if (null == comparer) 
        if (typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) ||
            typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
          comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

      if (null == comparer)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer", string.Format(
          "There's no default comparer for {0} class, you should provide it explicitly.", 
          typeof(T).Name));

      m_Comparer = comparer;
    }
    ...
  }
```

So you can create heaps

```
  // heap of integers, default comparer
  Heap<int> heap1 = new Heap<int>();

  // heap of integers, custom comparer (via lambda)
  Heap<int> heap2 = new Heap<int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => -x.CompareTo(y)));

  // heap of Buttons, custome comparer 
  Heap<Button> heap3 = new Heap<Button>(Comparer<Button>.Create((x, y) => ...));
```

And this will *throw exception*: no default comparer for `Button` class

```
  Heap<Button> heapErr = new Heap<Button>();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But should I throw or not throw exception? I mean, I can constrain T to be IComparable, so if "T" does not have a default comparer, I will able to detect the issue at compile time, not run time. Plese correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AnhHao Trần: I doubt if you should *constrain*: even if `T` doesn't have a *default* comparer, it seems to be reasonable to create `Heap<T>` but provide a *custom comparer*. Please, have a look at `List<T>.Sort`: you can try using default comparer when it's possible; you may provide a custom one and no constrains.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `IComparer<T>`, which is what all the collections in .NET use. For example:

```
public class Heap<T>
{
    private IComparer<T> comparer;
    private List<T> storage = new List<T>();     

    public Heap() : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public Heap(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    private void UpHeap(int position)
    {            
        for(var i = position; i > 0; i = (i - 1) >> 1)
        {
            // Check whether storage[i] is more Priority than storage[(i - 1) >> 1]
            if (comparer.Compare(storage[i], storage[(i - 1) >> 1]) > 0)
            {
                storage.Swap(i, (i - 1) >> 1);
            }
            else break;
        }
    }   
}
```

This has several advantages:

- You don't need the extra type parameter for the comparer, which is a lot more convenient when referencing the heap in other methods.
- There's no need to constrain `T` to be `IComparable`.
- However, if it does implement `ICompatable` (like `Int32` does), `Comparer<T>.Default` will use that implementation.